# How to use Botium Scripting Memory File

Tags: testing, command-line-interface, bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to learn how to use Botium Scripting Memory File. I have read the [wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48824412/Scripting+Memory+File) but couldnt make it work. Is there any sample or example using txt files and Botium Scripting Memory File to take a look at?

I'm using Botium-cli

Thank you.

Comment: Scripting memory is disabled by default - did you enable the SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY capability ? https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360603/Botium+Configuration+-+Capabilities#SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY

Comment: Yes I did. The Answer from Kirshnaa S helped me. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Botium-core [github page](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core) and navigate to the following folder [here](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botiumcore/tree/master/test/scripting/scriptingmemory)
Understand the way in which it's coded .Clone the project and run locally to understand it .use "mocha fillScriptingMemoryFromFile.spec.js " to directly run the scripting memory convofiles .If you're running from IDE use the command i gave you

Comment: Here's the link to scripting memory
" https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/tree/master/test/scripting/scriptingmemory "